# Send entries for FieldList of StringField from postman to flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, postman, wtforms

I'm trying to test a form created using wtform in flask using postman. In the form I have a FieldList of StringFields and I have specified minumum entries = 2. I have tried different solutions to test validations from postman, but always validation fails. I have tried testing by removing the fieldlist, the form validation works properly. I'm unable to send data as a list of stringfields from postman in x-www-form-urlencoded keyvalue format.
Code Snippets:

```
class PostUserForm(Form):
    email = StringField('email', [validators.DataRequired()])
    name = StringField('name', [validators.DataRequired()])
    words = FieldList(StringField('words',[validators.DataRequired()]), min_entries=2)


@apiV1.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def post_user():
    form = PostUserForm(request.form)
    print request.form
    if form.validate():
        return jsonify("correct data"), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(form.errors), 400
```

Following are Solutions I tried:
[image][image][image][image]Output:[image: Output same for all solutions]

Comment: Which validation errors are you getting?

Comment: The output screenshot shows the validation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found out how to do that, following screenshot shows the sample request[image]

Comment: you should’ve clarified that you changed `words` to `keywords` in `PostUserForm` 
 :)